# Error upon mvn clean install - MojoExecutionException

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, s4sdk

I'm currently using this setting for my project archetype:

```
mvn archetype:generate  
"-DarchetypeGroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.archetypes" 
"-DarchetypeArtifactId=scp-cf-tomee" "-DarchetypeVersion=2.1.2"  
"-DgroupId=com.sap.cloud.s4hana.examples" "-DarifactId=address-manager" 
"-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

My java version on my MacOS is:

```
java version "1.8.0_172"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_172-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.172-b11, mixed mode)
```

My JAVA_HOME:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Upon running, mvn clean install I get an error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire- 
plugin:3.0.0-M2:test (default-test) on project address-manager-unit- 
tests: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to 
/Users/XXXX/Documents/Personal/OpenSAP/Create and Deliver 
Cloud-Native SAP S:4HANA Extensions/S:4HANA Extensions/address- 
manager/unit-tests/target/surefire-reports for the individual test 
results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]- 
jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] ExecutionException The forked VM terminated without properly 
saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

Please find attached some screenshots of the same. I had changed the `pom.xml under unit tests to reflect version of surefire plugin as`3.0.0-M2`, but the error does not go away.

[image]  [image]

Any pointers to proceed would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which maven version do you use? Type `mvn -version` to find out. Also, I would try to use the most recent version of the SDK, so re-create a project with version `2.8.1` instead of `2.1.2`. I know that there was an update of surefire in between, but I'm not sure if this is related to the issue you have.

Comment: @FlorianWilhelm Thank you for your response. I am running maven version `3.5.2` and I just changed the pom.xml to reflect project version 2.8.1 instead of 2.1.2, imported dependencies from maven and ran `mvn clean install` and I still get the same error unfortunately.

Comment: There test failures in the project see `project address-manager-unit-tests: There are test failures.` ...please show those classes and the log details about them...

Comment: @khmarbaise The individual test results after I enabled "-e" switch looks like the following:  `# Created at 2018-12-16T11:02:47.876
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like the issue is that your path contains spaces and colons. I could reproduce the issue in that setup. Please re-try in a path without spaces and colons.

Best regards

Florian

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was it.