# Maven throwing no class found but is working on other developers environment

Tags: java, maven

I am getting the following error when running `mvn clean test`:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/plugin/MojoExecutionException`

It's not happening on my development team they say they are running the command just fine.

I've checked the `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` environments, both fine.

I'm using maven version `3.6.3` and Java version `1.8.0_144`

Not sure what to do at this point. This project was installed using IntelliJ git clone

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797860/maven-noclassdeffounderror-in-the-main-thread

Comment: Please post the full log file and the pom.xml. Furthermore do you build it with the bundled maven from IntelliJ or from command line?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53800797/error-upon-mvn-clean-install-mojoexecutionexception and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235430/maven-mojoexecutionexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was wrong with the maven donwload. I remapped the environment settings to use the intellij maven and everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ could use a bundled maven version, which could be different from the system/user one. Have you already checked settings of the IDE?

The problem could be related to different option, maybe a log could help more. Be sure that all the dependencies and plugins are downloaded without any problems. In the past I had same issue and it was related to the proxy settings for the download.